# Nature of Singularity for $f(z)=\sum_0^\infty \left(\frac{1-z}{1+z}\right)^n$

Tags: complex-analysis, laurent-series, singularity

Consider the function
$$f(z)=\sum_0^\infty \left(\frac{1-z}{1+z}\right)^n$$
It has an isolated singular point at $z=-1$. I'm trying to find the nature of this singular point. To do this, I have to do Laurent expansion of this around $-1$. I don't know how to do this. But how about an expansion in region $|z|<1$. Using the binomial expansion
$$\frac{1}{1-\zeta}=\sum_{k=0}^\infty \zeta^k$$
is valid provided that $|\zeta|<1$. We can write
$$\frac{1}{1+z}=\sum_{k=0}^\infty (-1)^k z^k$$
So that
$$f(z)=\sum_0^\infty (1-z)^n\left(\sum_{k=0}^\infty (-1)^kz^k\right)^n=\sum \left[(1-z)-(1-z)z+(1-z)z^2-\cdots  \right]^n$$
$$f(z)=\sum(1-2z+2z^2-2z^3+\cdots)^n$$
We can't use it to find the nature of singularity. Please help me with this.

Comment: Assume that $\Re z>0$ and use the geometric series your wrote down with the choice $\zeta =(1-z)/(1+z)$ to sum thes series and obtain a closed form for $f(z)$.

Answer (score 1):

$f$ is  not even defined in any deleted neighborhood of $-1$ because $|\frac {1-z} {1+z} | >3$ for $0 <|1+z| <1/2$. The series defining $f$ is divergent.

The series defining $f$ converges when $Re (z) >0$. Also, it converges uniformly on compact subsets of the right half plane. Hence, it has no singularites there.

Comment: Can you explain a bit, How you get that inequality?

Comment: $|1-z|=|2-(1+z)|\geq 2-|1+z| >2-\frac 1  2=\frac 3 2$ so the ratio is greater than $\frac {3/2} {1/2}=3$. @YoungKindaichi

Comment: Can I do the series expansion in region with $|1+z|>1/2$?

Comment: The series defining $f$ is defined  when  $|\frac {1-z} {1+z}| <1$ which is same as $Re (z) >0$. The question about singularity at $-1$ does not make sense.  @YoungKindaichi

Comment: There is an intersection between the region $Re(z)>0$ and $0<|z+1|<1/2$, How come the series can be defined there? Furthermore, In the problem, they didn't give specifically the singular point. Simply to find a singular point and find the nature of a singular point.

Comment: There is no intersection between those. $|1+z| <\frac 1  2$ implies $Re (z) <-\frac 1 2$ About your second question  see my edit now. @YoungKindaichi